# I am using System.Collections.ArrayList's COM object in my program. Does my end user needs dotnet?

Tags: .net, arraylist

I am using System.Collections.ArrayList's COM object in my program. This is the syntax

```
Local $aAlist = ObjCreate("System.Collections.ArrayList")
```

The language i am working with is AutoIt. But it lacks a dynamic array. By using ArrayList, i can easily use a dynamic array in my program. Does this method needs any dotnet framework in my end users PC ?

Comment: Yes, `ArrayList` is in `mscorlib`.

Comment: Is there any alternate way to do this ?